# Using a bat file to run r.report on large number TIFFs

Tags: python, qgis-3, grass-gis, bash

I need to process a large number of TIFFs or ASC that are also large in size, I was wondering if theres a way to run a bash script to call on r.report from GRASS to get the stats for my rasters and save them for further processing.

I've tried the following:

```
@ECHO ON 
SET path_in=directory 
SET path_out=directory 
FOR /F %%IN ('DIR /B %path_in%*.tif') DO (location of r.report.exe -n units=k "%path_in%infile"! !%path_out%!outfile!")
```

Comment: do you want a bash file or a bat file? but I'd expect the answer to be yes either way

Comment: Hello, a bat file, I've tried the following 
``` @ECHO ON
SET path_in=directory
SET path_out=directory

FOR /F %%IN ('DIR /B %path_in%*.tif')  DO (
location of r.report.exe -n units=k "%path_in%infile"! !%path_out%!outfile!")

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can run `r.report` from the command line on one file like this:

```bsh
grass --tmp-location foo.tif --exec bash -c "r.external input=foo.tif output=foo; r.report foo"
```

And if you have many, I would suggest using GNU `parallel` (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Perhaps something like:

```bsh
 parallel --bar "grass --tmp-location {1} --exec bash -c \"r.external input={1} output={1.}; r.report {1.} > {1.}.txt\"" ::: foo.tif bar.tif
```

And the part after `:::` can be replaced with, for example `$(ls *.tif)` if you have 100s or 1000s of them.

### Edit: Bash loop

Without using `parallel`, it could be:

```bsh
for f in $(ls *.tif); do
   grass --tmp-location ${f} --exec bash -c "r.external input=${f} output=raster; r.report raster > ${f}.report"
done
```

Which writes `file.tif.report` for each `file.tif`.

Comment: In your first suggestion can I not have input=(*.tiff) to select multiple tiffs? and have the output name same as the input name?

Comment: No, neither `r.external` nor any of the GRASS commands do bulk import. You need to loop over each file. You can import different files to the same name (overwriting them), and do `r.report` each time through the loop if you want.